# How to map through the knex stream data and modify the object before pipe it to the response?

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, node-streams

I'm using knex stream interface to stream the data from the table which has lot of records. I want to run some javascript code in each object of the array to modify the object and add extra parameters to the object. So, basically I'm trying to map through the stream and update the objects in the array before pipe it to the response in the api.

I tried something like -

```
pg('someTable').where(someCondition).pipe(JSONStream.parse()).map((item)=>{
  //updating the object
  return item
}).pipe(res)
```

But it's not working. I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance :)